# Can I use com.sap.cloud.servicesdk in local or NEO environment?

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-business-technology-platform

I would like to use the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Service Development in order to create odata-services the fancy and simple way :-)

```
@Query(serviceName = "EPMSampleService", entity = "Products")
public QueryResponse getAllProducts(QueryRequest queryRequest) {
```

I'have followed the instructions from the tutorial [Creating a Simple OData V4 Service That Exposes Mock Data](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8be3667edfd34d71a80afe9f7f2b42a9/Cloud/en-US/a7055aba5c2d4c068b4da87aa2e91679.html).

I am able to deploy and run it successfully in SAP Cloud Foundry, but my goal is to run it locally as well and later on SAP Neo Environment.

Therefore I've tried to deploy it on local SAP Server "Java Web Tomcat 8". The deployment was successful, I am also able to get $metadata. However once I call the Endpoint http://localhost:8080/quickstart/odata/v4/EPMSampleService/Products the following error message is returned:

> {"error":{"code":"Operation is not supported.","message":"Operation is not supported."}}

Any ideas if the SCP Service SDK can be used somehow locally and in SAP NEO?

Answer (score 2):

The SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development only supports the Cloud Foundry environment. Kindly take a look at the [official documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8be3667edfd34d71a80afe9f7f2b42a9/Cloud/en-US/ba01cc6734b4435c8ff52c9e0b93d779.html).

Comment: Thanks Sander. 
The SDK is great and I really would like to use it. If I use Cloud Foundry as a runtime environment, is it then still possible to use the NEO services like "Workflow" and "SAP Jam"?

Answer (score 0):

The error message {"error":{"code":"Operation is not supported.","message":"Operation is not supported."}} can be fixed by replacing the variable {packageName} in the web.xml with the actual package name from pom